# share access toke on xamarin forms

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I Have xamarin forms application, authenticate with asp.net membership and give accesstoken after authenticate.
In other platforms (ex silverlight, javascrip libs ....), this token access shared accross all requests to server (ex webclient,httpclient, image source request and ...) and all requests send it to server automaticaly
how can I share this token on xamarin forms for all requests?
I cant set cookies for all requests handly. because some of them like imagesource does not have any way to set it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a singleton implementation of this interface.

```
public interface IApiService
{
    HttpClient GetAuthorizedHttpClient();
}
```

When you first get your token,

set the aspNetToken field. Whenever making a request across your application, call GetAuthorizedHttpClient rather than instantiating a new one.

```
   public class ApiService : IApiService
    {

          private string aspNetToken; // set this once when instantiating
        private HttpClient HttpClient;

        protected HttpClient GetAuthorizedHttpClient()
        {
            if (HttpClient != null)
            {
                return HttpClient;
            }

            HttpClient = new HttpClient();

            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    aspNetToken
                );

            return HttpClient;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what about ImageSource from url?

Comment: @EhsanVali What about it?

Comment: I want to download images from server and need access token. for exampl <image source="http://hostname/downloade.ashx?ID=25" />

Comment: Store the token in a viewmodel variable and use it in a binding


<Image Source="{Binding Url}" />

public string Url => $"hostname/downloade.ashx?ID=25?token={yourToken}"

Comment: thanks for your replay.
I registered an issue and xamarin develop team accepted this suggestion as an enhancement
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10687